# PIX and Metro apps

Tags: directx, windows-8, pix

I would like to use Pix on a Metro (Win 8) app. However, Pix wants the path to the application, something that Metro apps don't have. Has anybody been able to get Pix working with Metro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PIX isn't going to work with non-desktop apps. The new way to debug these is the graphical debugger built into Visual Studio 2012. I'm also not sure PIX works properly on Win 8 for desktop apps either.

Comment: That's too bad. I keep getting an error with from the graphics debugger in VS 2012 and was looking for an alternative. Thanks!

Comment: What kind of error? Do you have Update 2 installed? That fixes up a number of graphics debugger issues.

Comment: I do have update 2 installed. The error is an exception thrown at a call to OMSetRenderTargets that only occurs when using the graphics debugger.